# How to read http rejection messages in websocket handshake by javascript?

Tags: javascript, websocket

A web page connects to the server via websocket. When initiating a connection, if the server finds the request is illegal, then it sends an http message directly with a non-200 status code to reject the connection process.

Now my program can receive the error event in `onerror()`, but I don't know how to get the http status code or body of that received http message?